# Any Asn1 implementation in Delphi

Tags: delphi, asn.1

Is there any nice asn1 implementation or libraries available in Delphi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [StreamSec ASN.1 Tools](http://www.streamsec.com/products_stasn1.asp), they are on the Partner DVD, too.

Comment: Broken link. Need update. Look product doesn't exists anymore.