# Can not import RSA keys generated with php openssl to windows CryptoAPI

Tags: php, delphi, encryption, openssl, cryptoapi

have problems importing keys generated with php openssl to CryptoAPI

I successfully create key pair in php, crypt/decrypt a string with it - no problems

```
<?php
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 1024,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA));

openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $s);

$info = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);
$public = openssl_pkey_get_public($info['key']);
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private($s);

$s = '';
$s1 = '';
openssl_public_encrypt('bla bla bla', $s, $public);
openssl_private_decrypt($s, $s1, $private);
echo('$s.'<br>'.$s1);
?>
```

Then I wrote a program in Delphi which should import private and public keys into CryptoAPI. I found some example private RSA key in internet and it imports with my code perfectly, but when I try to import a key generated with my php code it fails on **CryptDecodeObjectEx** function with **"asn1 bad tag value met"** error. Keys are quite similar except that php generates slightly longer key than I found in internet example, though they are both 1024 bits...

```
php generated key (does not work):
priv_key: string = 
    'MIICdwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmEwggJdAgEAAoGBAN/NfimL4/8Pmp7+' +
    'j299I7yaT6SpF1jwrFlwlLLjDibehqjBOcao+CaLK8Se+hysqZGGwr2walUprGxG' +
    'Z5hnfCQCOchbTs5CiXnBCIX1aPKaRMx/SX3b4moT+wnkLrGOnHnUM+2c+jqZUjdh' +
    '06hwlv1LCVcCtTW9NWU3Qi3G+r9bAgMBAAECgYBjjuSK0uJP+r8L764bKI4XPoYj' +
    'd90dAaOJ/h0IHx2SiPdaZuqux0fszYhg5V/aFa0xQcOr4qjKzckYOZGoKJD+FtCq' +
    'bNBEg1eZsKWYVJvTO8N2H0Lx4VSCiG7PjiqLGFfsmXZDXLPXhzsuCOUACmfcVoqh' +
    'NlXOEAKtaTZI+uAakQJBAPB8sIQN7xTgCQcP2F8IbWR3VRAlnr4LWZQ5k96uxWjC' +
    'wC6R8c7NnvUj+Fzs3XMXR8e3aTRme9OyHAWy7ReO+scCQQDuPUjBXXxuYGQq4ho5' +
    'Pq4QEtHNKECDNDtKBaLvr9r7aXYOfMM/XiXqFqHAZqcrTRtMXD1sUhg4o+vIYkrg' +
    '5qLNAkEA6+Z0RGVitAh78ohxh+89V4LTV05/5A5AJe1BBvxLu1LmsAgLuf/rwK4z' +
    'L/xN0lrw15EryvII34VkhZaZijV/+wJAfX52xrTSCOppmVVE7wafdgQT0/fyE6r9' +
    '2D4j2BJQTcL91x/NUaHsYuTNC6aHRH33dT/ZcyfDboKafxGX0+RpuQJBAMdPGszm' +
    'JYhD9F8kz+Q9R04iuwupLxUU6Q60yVVZxRDBQ7OLxBQwrHa2WQ0TA8WC73TMNaph' +
    'VN4ayHJHK8shjt0=';

example key (works fine and it is shorter than php key):
priv_key: string =
    'MIICXAIBAAKBgQCf6YAJOSBYPve1jpYDzq+w++8YVoATI/YCi/RKZaQk+l2ZfoUQ' +
    'g0qrYrfkzeoOa/qd5VLjTTvHEgwXnlDXMfo+vSgxosUxDOZXMTBqJGOViv5K2QBv' +
    'k8A1wi4k8tuo/7OWya29HvcfavUk3YXaV2YFe8V6ssaZjNcVWmDdjqNkXwIDAQAB' +
    'AoGALrd+ijNAOcebglT3ioE1XpUbUpbir7TPyAqvAZUUESF7er41jY9tnwgmBRgL' +
    'Cs+M1dgLERCdKBkjozrDDzswifFQmq6PrmYrBkFFqCoLJwepSYdWnK1gbZ/d43rR' +
    '2sXzSGZngscx0CxO7KZ7xUkwENGd3+lKXV7J6/vgzJ4XnkECQQDTP6zWKT7YDckk' +
    'We04hbhHyBuNOW068NgUUvoZdBewerR74MJx6nz28Tp+DeNvc0EveiQxsEnbV8u+' +
    'NRkX5y0xAkEAwcnEAGBn5kJd6SpU0ALA9XEpUv7tHTAGQYgCRbfTT59hhOq6I22A' +
    'ivjOCNG9c6E7EB2kcPVGuCpYUhy7XBIGjwJAK5lavKCqncDKoLwGn8HJdNcyCIWv' +
    'q5iFoDw37gTt1ricg2yx9PzmabkDz3xiUmBBNeFJkw/FToXiQRGIakyGIQJAJIem' +
    'PPPvYgZssYFbT4LVYO8d/Rk1FWVyKHQ9CWtnmADRXz7oK7l+m7PfEuaGsf9YpOcR' +
    'koGJ/TluQLxNzUNQnQJBAImwr/yYFenIx3HQ6UX/fCt6qpGDv0VfOLyR64MNeegx' +
    'o7DhNxHbFkIGzk4lKhMKcHKDrawZbdJtS9ie2geSwVQ=';
```

Code in Delphi which imports key:

```
var
  dwBufferLen, cbKeyBlob, i: longword;
  pbBuffer, pbKeyBlob: pointer;
  hProv: HCRYPTPROV;
  hKey: HCRYPTKEY;
begin
  hProv := 0;
  hKey := 0;

  // convert key string to a binary
  if not(CryptStringToBinary(PWideChar(priv_key), 0, 1, nil, @dwBufferLen, nil, nil)) then
    exit;

  GetMem(pbBuffer, dwBufferLen);
  if not(CryptStringToBinary(PWideChar(priv_key), 0, 1, pbBuffer, @dwBufferLen, nil, nil)) then
    exit;

  // convert binary to a key blob
  if not(CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
     PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, pbBuffer, dwBufferLen, 0, nil, nil, @cbKeyBlob)) then
    begin
      // first key generates error here
      ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      exit;
    end;

  GetMem(pbKeyBlob, cbKeyBlob);
  if not(CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
     PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, pbBuffer, dwBufferLen, 0, nil, pbKeyBlob, @cbKeyBlob)) then
    exit;

  if not(CryptAcquireContext(@hProv, nil, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL,
     CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) then
    exit;

  if not(CryptImportKey(hProv, pbKeyBlob, cbKeyBlob, 0, 0, @hKey)) then
    exit;

  //...

  if hKey <> 0 then
    CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
  if hProv <> 0 then
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0); 
end;
```

Comment: Did you try to see what is different between the two different keys (that might explain why the Windows API function complains). You should decode the Base64/ASN.1 encoded key. SO even gives a hint on how to decode an ASN.1 document here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153059/any-asn1-implementation-in-delphi

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I checked them and see that php generated key has some extra fields added compare to CryptoAPI key. Do you have any idea how to make php create keys without adding extra info? Maybe some flags passed to openssl_pkey_new? This function is not documented well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
PHP generates keys with extra fields in ASN.1 format compare to CryptoAPI keys.
1. I decoded base64 key into a binary file with help of this tool: [base64 decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Decode/Default.aspx)
2. Then I just cut from this file first 26 bytes to the next header sequence starting from something like: "30 xx xx" and saved it.
3. And encoded this file back to base64 with: [base64 encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/Default.aspx)

Now I can import public and private keys into CryptoAPI without problems with next code:

```
// key types
const
  PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = LPCSTR(43);
  PKCS_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY = LPCSTR(19);

function ImportKey(hProv: HCRYPTPROV; KeyType: pointer; key: string): hKey;
var
  BuffSize, BlobSize: longword;
  buff, blob: pointer;
begin
  result := 0;
  buff := nil;
  blob := nil;

  try
    if not(CryptStringToBinary(PWideChar(key), 0, 1, nil, @BuffSize, nil, nil)) then
      exit;

    GetMem(buff, BuffSize);
    if not(CryptStringToBinary(PWideChar(key), 0, 1, buff, @BuffSize, nil, nil)) then
      exit;

    if not(CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
       KeyType, buff, BuffSize, 0, nil, nil, @BlobSize)) then
      exit;

    GetMem(blob, BlobSize);
    if not(CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
       KeyType, buff, BuffSize, 0, nil, blob, @BlobSize)) then
      exit;

    if not(CryptImportKey(hProv, blob, BlobSize, 0, 0, @result)) then
      exit;

  finally
    if buff <> nil then
      FreeMem(buff);
    if blob <> nil then
      FreeMem(blob);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar situation where I was generating keys using PHP5's openssl API, and importing them using Windows CryptoAPI, except I'm using C++.

The 26 byte offset fixed importing private keys for me, but I found the offset for public keys to be 24 bytes. As Mike K. pointed out, you need to offset until the next header sequence, I found that the first two bytes of the sequence will be "30 82".  So if you run into a situation where 24 bytes or 26 bytes doesn't work, check out the key in a hex editor and look for those bytes.

Here is the code I had success with:

```
DWORD PEMToPublicKeyBlob(char* keyData, DWORD keyDataLen, BYTE** publicKeyBlob, DWORD* length)
{
    DWORD ret = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    wchar_t message[256];

    BYTE* der = NULL;
    DWORD derLen = 0;

    unsigned int offset = 0;
    // if the header is this, and not -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- the key was created on the webserver
    if(strstr(keyData, "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" ))
        offset = 24;        // php puts 24 extra bytes in the header that screws up the import

    // Convert from PEM format to DER format
    // get length
    if (!CryptStringToBinaryA(keyData, keyDataLen, CRYPT_STRING_ANY, NULL, &derLen, NULL, NULL))
    {
        ret = GetLastError();
        swprintf_s(message, 256, L"PEMToPublicKeyBlob: CryptStringToBinaryA(len) failed %u", ret);
        writeToLog(message);
        goto out;
    }

    der = new BYTE[derLen];
    if(!der)
    {
        ret = ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
        swprintf_s(message, 256, L"PEMToPublicKeyBlob: der blob allocation failed %u", ret);
        writeToLog(message);
        goto out;
    }
    if (!CryptStringToBinaryA(keyData, keyDataLen, CRYPT_STRING_ANY, der, &derLen, NULL, NULL))
    {
        ret = GetLastError();
        swprintf_s(message, 256, L"PEMToPublicKeyBlob: CryptStringToBinaryA failed %u", ret);
        writeToLog(message);
        goto out;
    }

    // Decode from DER format to PUBLICKEYBLOB
    // get length
    *length = 0;
    if (!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB,
                                der + offset, derLen - offset, 0, NULL, NULL, length))
    {
        ret = GetLastError();
        swprintf_s(message, 256, L"PEMToPublicKeyBlob: CryptDecodeObjectEx(len) failed %u", ret);
        writeToLog(message);
        goto out;
    }

    *publicKeyBlob = new BYTE[*length];
    if(!*publicKeyBlob)
    {
        ret = ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
        swprintf_s(message, 256, L"PEMToPublicKeyBlob: publickey blob allocation failed %u", ret);
        writeToLog(message);
        goto out;
    }

    if (!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB,
                                der + offset, derLen - offset, 0, NULL, *publicKeyBlob, length))
    {
        ret = GetLastError();
        swprintf_s(message, 256, L"PEMToPublicKeyBlob: CryptDecodeObjectEx failed %u", ret);
        writeToLog(message);
        goto out;
    }
out:
    if(der) delete[] der;
    return ret;
}
```

The code for importing private keys is pretty much the same except you specify PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY instead of RSA_CSP_PUBLICKEYBLOB.

Answer (score 0):

The proper code (e.g. without using "magical numbers") would be:

```
{
Remove optional ASN.1 header from source.

Header:
Offset| Len  |LenByte|
======+======+=======+======================================================================
     0|   630|      3| SEQUENCE :
     4|     1|      1|    INTEGER : 0
     7|    13|      1|    SEQUENCE :
     9|     9|      1|       OBJECT IDENTIFIER : rsaEncryption [1.2.840.113549.1.1.1]
    20|     0|      1|       NULL :
    22|   608|      3|    OCTET STRING / BIT STRING:
                             ... actual key data ...
}
function ASN1SkipOptionalHeader(const ADER: DATA_BLOB): DATA_BLOB;
const
  ASN1_INTEGER     = $02;
  ASN1_BITSTRING   = $03;
  ASN1_OCTETSTRING = $04;
  ASN1_SEQUENCE    = $30;
var
  P: PByte;
  Len: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := ADER;
  P := Result.pbData;

  // Check for header:
  // SEQUENCE:
  //   INTEGER
  //   SEQUENCE
  //   OCTET STRING/BIT STRING
  // or:
  // SEQUENCE:
  //   SEQUENCE
  //   OCTET STRING/BIT STRING

  // both header and any key start with ASN1_SEQUENCE, skip it
  if P^ <> ASN1_SEQUENCE then
    Exit;
  Inc(P);
  ASN1ReadLength(P);

  // both header and key have ASN1_INTEGER as first field, skip it
  if P^ = ASN1_INTEGER then
  begin
    Inc(P);
    Len := ASN1ReadLength(P);
    Inc(P, Len);
  end;

  // now, check if it is a header or a key
  // a header has ASN1_SEQUENCE as second field,
  // a key has ASN1_INTEGER as second field
  if P^ <> ASN1_SEQUENCE then
    Exit;
  Inc(P);
  Len := ASN1ReadLength(P);
  Inc(P, Len);

  // now, seek to real key data
  if P^ = ASN1_OCTETSTRING then
  begin
    Inc(P);
    Result.cbData := ASN1ReadLength(P);
    Result.pbData := P;
  end
  else
  if P^ = ASN1_BITSTRING then
  begin
    Inc(P);
    Result.cbData := ASN1ReadLength(P) - 1;
    if P^ = 0 then // unused bits must be 0
    begin
      Inc(P);
      Result.pbData := P;
    end
    else
      Result.cbData := ADER.cbData; // fail, not support non-zero unused bits
  end;

{
  Now Result should be:

Offset| Len  |LenByte|
======+======+=======+======================================================================
     0|   604|      3| SEQUENCE :
     4|     1|      1|    INTEGER : 0
     7|   129|      2|    INTEGER :
      |      |       |       00... cut ...65
   139|     3|      1|    INTEGER : 65537
   144|   128|      2|    INTEGER :
      |      |       |       29... cut ...51
   275|    65|      1|    INTEGER :
      |      |       |       00... cut ...8F
   342|    65|      1|    INTEGER :
      |      |       |       00... cut ...CB
   409|    64|      1|    INTEGER :
      |      |       |       61... cut ...05
   475|    64|      1|    INTEGER :
      |      |       |       3D... cut ...11
   541|    65|      1|    INTEGER :
      |      |       |       00... cut ...37
}
end;

function ASN1ReadLength(var P: PByte): Cardinal;
var
  B: Byte;
begin
  Result := 0;
  B := P^;
  Inc(P);
  if B and $80 <> 0 then
  begin
    B := B and $7F;
    if B > 4 then
    begin
      Result := 0;
      Exit;
    end;
    if B > 0 then
    begin
      while B > 0 do
      begin
        Result := (Result shl 8) or P^;
        Inc(P);
        Dec(B);
      end;
    end
    else
      Result := 0;
  end
  else
    Result := B;
end;
```